# Google analytics vs. chartbeat analytics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, chartbeat

I am using Google analytics page views tracking with ga.js.
I am getting a significantly lower current users statistic than with Chartbeat (I put it in for comparison).
Only the page views with a cookie to allow for it are sent to Google analytics, same with Chartbeat. Yet there's like a 200% difference.

I am using this code for GA (ofcourse I first check for cookie existence):

```
_gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-59585362-2']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
createAnalyticsScript();

var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
```

This code is directy copied from Google.

Does anyone have an idea why I get such different statistics (GA is not tracking all of my page views)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Doubled other metrics?

If there is 200% difference, dont you have doubled chartbeat?

### What is cookie to allow?

Is that something like user opt-out parameter? So it tracks only users who agreed to be tracked?

Comment: Actually it's more than 200%. When there's around 7 users tracked on GA, there's like 42 on chartbeat. 

Yes, it tracks only users who agree to be tracked (there's a pop up on the site).

Comment: And is chartbeat behind this pop up, or it track all even they did not agree? Is it realy "one to one" analytic systems integration?

Comment: Both are behind popups.

Comment: It is strange. I need more information about implementation (extend your question). What is createAnalyticsScript ? What about subdomains? Are they tracked by these two systems together? Or only a part is in GA and rest in CB? How is you callback method for cookie opt-out looking like?